# CakePHP routes in 1.3 trying to define a route for an extra cosmetic parameter to be included?

Tags: cakephp, routes

### eg my URLs and their resulting actions , will be like:

1) a: For a user whose company_id belongs to company = Pepsi

```
/pepsi/ - controller - users, action - dashboard (their Auth->user 'company_id' will be used and their user->id)

/pepsi/companies/view - controller - companies, action - view
/pepsi/users/ - controller - users, action - index (trailing slash preferably optional)
/pepsi/users/dashboard - controller - users, action - dashboard
```

1) b: For a user who company_id belongs to company = Coke

```
/coke/ - controller - users, action - dashboard
/coke/companies/view - controller - companies, action - view
/coke/users/ - controller - users, action - index (trailing slash preferably optional)
/coke/users/dashboard - controller - users, action - dashboard
```

2) For an admin, which uses routing prefix adminperson

```
/adminperson/users - controller - users, action - index
/adminperson/users/view/3 - controller - users, action - view , id = 3
/adminperson/companies/delete/6 - controller - companies, action - delete Id = 6
```

3) *important* Then also when a user isnt logged in , there are ALSO public pages.
    /contents/view/3 - controller - contents, action - view AND id = 3

Below is the best I have got so far, but it always demands the action index to be explicitly written to the URL - but in fact I guess its not that bad a problem as the Html->link helper should produce it. I am happy to build all my links with the helper as I usually do that.

## best try :

```
Router::connect('/:companyslug/:controller/:action', array('controller' => 'companies', 'action'=>'index', 'companyslug'=>'test'));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have a similar setup, except I'm keeping track of the first part of the route to determine what records are displayed. Here's my setup, where ":app" is in place of what you call ":companyslug":

```
$app_names = "app1|app2|test_app"; // In real code these are pulled from a model

Router::connect(
    '/:app/:controller/:action/*', 
    array( ), 
    array(
        'persist'=>array('app'),
        'app'=>$app_names
    )
);

Router::connect(
    '/:app/:controller', 
    array('action'=>'index'), 
    array(
        'persist'=>array('app'),
        'app'=>$app_names
    )
);

Router::connect(
    '/:app', 
    array('controller'=> 'pages', 'action'=>'display', 'home'), 
    array(
        'persist'=>array('app'),
        'app'=>$app_names
    )
);

// Allow non-app specific access. (I have disabled the default CakePHP routes.)
Router::connect('/:controller', array('action' => 'index'));
Router::connect('/:controller/:action/*');
```

Note: this is from Cake 2.0RC3, but I believe it should work the same in 1.3.

This way you can retrieve the value of app in the controller (under request parameters) and make sure they are in the correct URL (make sure company_id = companyslug in your case).

One tricky bit is the 'persist' option, which means you always need to use the Html Helper's link function to maintain the correct prefix in the URL.

Comment: hey thanks this looks interesting - I will try this and get back! I was trying to avoid a db query but it might be of use anyway.

Comment: @boobyWomack The db query isn't required. You could hard-code a list, but only if the list isn't supposed to be dynamic. In my case, the apps list is dynamic.

Comment: hi cheers I worked out a way to cache a db call so might just use this too now. I am not sure I would need the "allow non-app specific access" lines, as shouldnt it already do that? i.e it wouldnt find a valid entry in my $app_names so would continue on...and arent what you give basically the default routes? thanks for your help so far.

Comment: oh do you mean in my views I *must* always use $this->Html->link and never hadncode a <a href="/path/to/app/controller/action" style link? I try to do this anyhow, I guess it will break if I don't! 

I guess I would also need to do $this->Html->link('action'=>'someaction', 'app'=>false) if I want to remove the company slug prefix at points?

Comment: Yes, the default routes will take care of the "Allow non-app specific access" section of my code. I have it there as I've disabled the default CakePHP routing. Sorry that wasn't clear. Also I should explain that those aren't required at all. If you want (and I may be doing this in my app) you could remove those lines and force all access to be done through the slug prefix.

Comment: Per your second question, it's best that you always use $this->Html->link() to ensure the prefix is maintained. If you hardcode a link, you'll need to make sure you account for the prefix manually, (which is more difficult). 

If you want to make a non-prefixed link you can either use the $this->Html->link() as you describe, or hardcode it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **Regex** in route, like -

```
Router::connect('/:companyslug/:controller/:action', array('controller' => 'companies', 'action'=>'index'),  array('companyslug'=>'[A-Za-z0-9_\-]*'));
```

Comment: The regex needs to be the third argument. You have it as part of the second. http://book.cakephp.org/view/945/Routes-Configuration#Defining-Routes-948

Comment: @DaveLancea hey thank you very much, I've fixed. I was a mistake :)

Comment: this is slightly irrelevant in that the regex won't change the way the route *behaves* but it is needed adding later anyway.